# Check value of cell versus previous row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress-mvc

Currently I'm working on a grid that had some interesting logic.  The logic within it currently was put in place to keep from showing duplicate data in a row.

By that, I mean this.  I have a grid with multiple columns (10).  Currently, a process is set up in the HtmlDataCellPrepared method to check to see if the value of the cell is equal to a session variable.  If it is, then leave it blank.  Below is the code to show what happens.

```
settings.HtmlDataCellPrepared = (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "ProgramArea")
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["QR_ProgramArea"] != null &&
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["QR_ProgramArea"].ToString() == e.CellValue.ToString())
                    e.Cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
                HttpContext.Current.Session["QR_ProgramArea"] = e.CellValue.ToString();
            }
```

My goal is to replace this session variable due that there are times that nothing at all is populated within the column.  I need to compare the current value versus the row before.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a solution after a bit more research.  The easiest way to eliminate the Session variables would be to look at the previous row's data to see if the same value exists.

```
settings.HtmlDataCellPrepared = (sender, e) =>
{
    var grid = sender as MVCxGridView;
    if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "ProgramArea")
    {
        if (e.VisibleIndex - 1 >= 0)
        {
            var previousRow = grid.GetDataRow(e.VisibleIndex - 1);
            if (e.CellValue.ToString() == previousRow["ProgramArea"].ToString())
                e.Cell.Text = "&nbsp;";
        }
    }
```

Naturally you skip the 1st row, but after that, look at each row and see if the previous row had the same data.